# AVPlayer Video Playback No Sound

Tags: objective-c, avplayer

I'm using AVPlayer to play back some embedded (.mov) video clips in the bundle and I can't get the audio to playback. Any advice on how to get the audio to play? All I see is the video playing with no audio.

Comment: Did you figure why was not playing the audio?, I'm having the same issue with mp4 file.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the audio in the movie is using one of the support audio codecs. These are listed in the [Multimedia Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH2-SW9) if you're using iOS. If you're using OS X, then [this list](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH2-SW9) might be more appropriate.